# What is cloudformation script for S3 replication configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, replication

I was looking for cloudformation script for S3 bucket replication between two buckets within the same account. I am able to create one myself, answering this in case someone is looking for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the cloudformation script that can create bucket, iam role needed for repliation and setup replication at the same time.

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
"Description": "Create bucket and setup replication",

"Parameters": {
    "sourceBucketName": {
        "Description": "Name for the source bucket",
        "Type": "String"
    },
    "destinationBucketName": {
        "Description": "Name for the destination bucket",
        "Type": "String"
    }
},

"Resources": {

    "BucketRole": {
        "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
        "Condition": "IsProdSourceBucket",
        "Properties": {
            "Path": "/",
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Principal": {"Service": ["s3.amazonaws.com"]},
                        "Action": ["sts:AssumeRole"],
                        "Effect": "Allow"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Policies": [
                {
                    "PolicyName": "bucket-replication-permissions",
                    "PolicyDocument": {
                        "Version": "2012-10-17",
                        "Statement": [
                            {
                                "Effect": "Allow",
                                        "Action": [
                                            "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
                                            "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl"
                                        ],
                                        "Resource": [
                                            {"Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:s3:::${sourceBucketName}/*"}
                                        ]
                            },
                            {
                                "Effect": "Allow",
                                "Action": [
                                    "s3:ListBucket",
                                    "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration"
                                ],
                                "Resource": [
                                    {"Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:s3:::${sourceBucketName}"}
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "Effect": "Allow",
                                "Action": [
                                    "s3:ReplicateObject",
                                    "s3:ReplicateDelete",
                                    "s3:ReplicateTags",
                                    "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging"
                                ],
                                "Resource": {"Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:s3:::${destinationBucketName}/*"}
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },

    "BucketConfiguration": {
        "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
        "DeletionPolicy": "Retain",
        "Properties": {
            "BucketName": {"Ref": "sourceBucketName"},
            "VersioningConfiguration": {
                "Status": "Enabled"
            },
            "ReplicationConfiguration": { 
                "Role" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "BucketRole", "Arn" ] },
                "Rules" : [{
                            "Destination" : {"Bucket": {"Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:s3:::${destinationBucketName}"}},
                            "Prefix" : "",
                            "Status" : "Enabled"
                        }]
            }
        }
    }
},

"Outputs": {
    "BucketConfiguration": {
        "Description": "Optimizer configuration files.",
        "Value": {"Ref": "BucketConfiguration"},
        "Export": {"Name": "BucketConfiguration"}
    },
    "BucketConfigurationARN": {
        "Description": "Optimizer configuration files.",
        "Value": {"Fn::GetAtt": ["BucketConfiguration", "Arn"]},
        "Export": {"Name": "BucketConfigurationARN"}
    }
}
```

}

References:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr-walkthrough1.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html